# Load in an unknown number of files in a specific directory

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, streamreader

I'm trying to load an unknown number of json files in a directory using json.net (C:/users/Nathan/Documents/test)

I want to be able to add json files to this directory and no matter how many there are my program should be able to access all of them and load them as separate a  jObject with unique names.

Is this even possible?

**Edit** I don't have code yet, I have to get ideas what direction to take for this.

Comment: Yes it's possible but without showing your code,  how can we say if there is a better way?

Comment: you may want to take a look at Directory.GetFiles() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't have any code yet, I'm new at this so I have no ideas

Comment: @user2712963, if you are new to a programming languge the first step should be to look into the documentation or tutorials. MSDN documentation is not that bad. Note that the .NET framework organizes the functionalities it offers in [namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your case, what you want to know is about I/O, so you should first look into the [System.IO namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find some class with methods that help you achieve what you want...

Comment: This is not a site where you can ask people to write code for you. You need to do some research and make an attempt yourself. Then, if you have problems, post the code you tried and describe how what it does is different from what you want.

Comment: @Blackwood this is part of my research process. I've been researching this for a while and I was totally lost. so I came to ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code would be something like below:

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\user\Nathan\Documents\test");

foreach(var file in fileNames)
{ 
  using (var sr = File.OpenText(file))
  using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
  {
    var json = (JObject) JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
  }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try.

Comment: You probably need to install Newtonsoft.json. Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: that's what I'm using!

Answer (score 0):

Use `string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("C:/users/Nathan/Documents/test")` to get all the file names in a specific directory. Also, this can throw an exception if the directory does not exist.

Comment: forward slash still works, it's just not the "proper way". @kaveman I used the asker example.

Comment: @kaveman, forward slashes are okay. That .NET deals just fine with forward slashes makes especially sense if you consider programs using relative paths which should run in different environments, like your C# program running in Windows as well as running on some other (Unix-like) platform supported by Mono...